# position a div off screen in Opera Mobile (overflow:hidden not working)

Tags: css, responsive-design, opera-mobile

I'm working on a responsive web layout, with a menu that is positioned off screen - basically I'm using the following code:

**CSS:**

```
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
.offscreen {
    background:#F00;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    right:-90px;
    top:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div class="offscreen">
    </div>
</body>
```

Demo can be found [here](http://www.thebackoffice.be/revaki/static/test.html).

**The problem:**
Opera Mobile (12.10 on Android 4.1.2) positions the div off screen, but allows scrolling - apparently it ignores the `overflow:hidden` rule.

[image: Demo page]

**My question:**

- Any ideas how I can make Opera Mobile hide the div & disable the horizontal scroll?

Comment: Have you got a [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) defined?

Comment: Viewport is set to `width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the `viewport` - I used ; as a seperator instead of , on the live example. This already fixed the second part of my problem (difference between demo & live example)

Comment: @ptriek hi! Did you found a cure a far-far ago? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
overflow:hidden; 
overflow-y:hidden; 
overflow-x:hidden;
```

Not tested.